# How to set Postgres Datetime field into Odoo Datetime field

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, odoo-10

I am trying to display set time of Postgres database time to datetime field into Odoo.

I am creating field is that to set the time.

```
last_modify_article = fields.Datetime("Last Modify Date")
```

But my DateTime :~ 2017-08-28T08:43:56+0200 is perfectly stored in Postgres database but in Odoo saw in different.

So, my question is that how can I manage the database date-time in the field.

[Here is the Postgres Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz31j.png)

And

[Here is Odoo field to set datetime in UTC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajinE.png)

Answer (score 9):

Actually the database stores the `Datetime` field according to the system timezone. In Odoo, views which will be automatically converted according to the user's timezone if it is set.

On your images, I can see the time difference id +5:30 ie, Asia/Kolakata timezone. So your custom operations on `Datetime` field need the proper conversion of Timezone according to the user.

Odoo views and ORM methods are treated the `tz` with `moment.js` and the `pytz` conversions. This is actually a good feature to manage different timezones in Odoo.

You can use `astimezone` on `Datetime` objects:

```
def astimezone(self, tz): # known case of datetime.datetime.astimezone
    """ tz -> convert to local time in new timezone tz """
    return datetime(1, 1, 1)
```

or

```
fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, datetime.strptime(value, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT))
```

Answer (score 4):

Odoo is designed to have the date and time stored as UTC in the database and convert it to the user's timezone on the front-end.

What time zone is set for your user? You can click your name in the top right, then Preferences. Time zone should be shown on the popup form.

Comment: yes you right to Odoo is set to UTC but my time is correct in the database so how I can print same time in the field. And I am working with a different country so I can not assign timezone into my Preferences. and If I assign timezone its mismatch with the browser. so that way I print same as database value in my field value

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi Are you manually setting the time in the database (or in Python) or is it set from the Odoo frontend?

Comment: actually I working with API so I can get the API and set the DateTime field

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytz library to convert datetime based on user's timezone. See the code sample.

```
import pytz
import datetime

    def current_user_datetime(self):
        currenttimezone = pytz.timezone(self.env.context.get('tz'))
        user_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(currenttimezone)
        self.timefield = user_datetime
```